# A whiptail box disappears during a script execution within the SHH session

Tags: bash, ssh, whiptail

I've rote script to make user to choose some role to restart.

```bash
## Check the restart roles option
if [[ $RESTART_ROLE != 0 ]]
then
    whiptail --title "Restarting the services" --msgbox "Please choose the roles to restart specific services" 8 45
    
    RESTART_ROLE=$(whiptail --title  "Restarting the services" --menu  "Please choose the roles to restart specific services" 15 60 8 --nocancel \
    "master" "" \
    "monitoring" "" \
    "worker" "" \
    "balancer" "" \
    "correlator" "" \
    "data" "" \
    "eventsrouter" "" \
    "flow-balancer" ""  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
fi
```

Of course user can't watch the `RESTART_ROLE=whiptale`, but can choose the answer.

I've googled that problem and found solution: I've put simple `whiptail` box before the main box.

First time it worked, but after a system reboot I could watch the first `whiptail`, and the second was disappeared.

The ssh `-t` option also doesn't help.

Should I reset the terminal during an SSH session? Or use `tput setaf` command?